# Cygwin .bashrc not being source because cygwin starting in Windows home

Tags: bash, cygwin, bashrc

NOTE: Please see my second edit below for an update on the problem.

Cygwin was working fine for me until last week. Now .bashrc isn't getting sourced. I must have installed something or changed something but I can't remember exactly what caused the problem. When I start Cygwin, I'm in my Windows home and none of my aliases work. I have to manually source .bashrc. The following is my Cygwin.bat:

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

set CYGWIN=tty notitle glob

bash --login -i
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: My .bash_profile contains the following,

```
# source the users bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi
```

EDIT2: IMPORTANT! When I started Cygwin it starts in my Windows home folder. I tried putting my .bash_profile and .bashrc in this folder and they were sourced correctly! This means that the problem has been reduced to figuring out why Cygwin starts in the Windows home folder and not the normal Cygwin home folder.

EDIT3: Results of running grep Gulshan /etc/passwd/

```
$ grep Gulshan /etc/passwd
Administrator:unused:500:513:U-Gulshan-HP\Administrator,S-1-5-21-1235613160-4193452482-2032876723-500:/home/Administrator:/bin/bash
Guest:unused:501:513:U-Gulshan-HP\Guest,S-1-5-21-1235613160-4193452482-2032876723-501:/home/Guest:/bin/bash
Gulshan:unused:1000:513:U-Gulshan-HP\Gulshan,S-1-5-21-1235613160-4193452482-2032876723-1000:/home/Gulshan:/bin/bash
```

Comment: When your bash shell starts (and puts you in your Windows home directory), what does `echo $HOME` print?

Comment: It echoes my Windows home, not my Cygwin home.

Comment: But using Cygwin syntax, right?  (`/cygdrive/c/Users/foo` rather than `C:\Users\foo`)

Comment: Yes, using Cygwin syntax.

Comment: What happens when you type `HOME=/home/yourname bash -l` at the terminal prompt?  If I'm right, this should give you properly working shell.  Note that this is a diagnostic, or at best a workaround, not a solution; we still need to figure out why your `$HOME` is incorrect in the first place.  The root problem is the incorrect setting of `$HOME`; bash is behaving correctly.

Comment: Yes, that command works, thanks. How can we go about debugging what changed the $HOME variable?

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.setup.home) explains how `$HOME` is set:

> When starting Cygwin from Windows, `HOME` is determined as follows in
>   order of decreasing priority:
>
> - `HOME` from the Windows environment, translated to POSIX form.
> - The entry in `/etc/passwd`
> - `/home/USERNAME`
>
> When using Cygwin from the network (telnet, ssh,...), `HOME` is set
>   from `/etc/passwd`.
>
> If your `HOME` is set to a value such as `/cygdrive/c`, it is likely
>   that it was set in Windows. Start a DOS Command Window and type `set
>   HOME` to verify if this is the case.
>
> Access to shared drives is often restricted when starting from the
>   network, thus Domain users may wish to have a different `HOME` in the
>   Windows environment (on shared drive) than in `/etc/passwd` (on local
>   drive). Note that ssh only considers `/etc/passwd`, disregarding
>   `HOME`.

My best guess is that you've messed up your `/etc/passwd` file.  (The Windows home directory is `%USERPROFILE%`, not `%HOME%`.)

What does `grep USERNAME /etc/passwd` print (replacing `USERNAME` with your user name)?

Comment: I've added the output to my question so it's easier to read. It looks like it's set correctly there. However, I opened up my Windows Environment variables to see if there was a %HOME% variable and there was and it was set to %USERPATH%. I removed it, but it didn't solve my issue. Maybe it needs a restart?

Comment: Did you remove it from the System control panel, or from a Windows command shell using `set HOME=`?  Using the System control panel is more likely to work, but a restart might be necessary even then.

Comment: I removed it by right clicking on Computer in the start menu, clicking on properties, clicking on advanced system settings, then environment variables, and then removing HOME. A restart was necessary. Now Cygwin loads the right home directory. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .profile or .bash_profile, that is sourced on login shells, and you get a login shell since you pass `--login`. If you source .profile, then bash will *not* source .bashrc.

I'd try to put:

```
[ -f $HOME/.bashrc ] && source $HOME/.bashrc
```

in your .profile, see if that helps. Your .bashrc should still be sourced, as normal, in other non-login shell invocations.

And don't pass `-i` to bash; you don't need it. Bash kind of hacks that in, pretends you gave `-i` on the command line.

Comment: My .bash_profile and .profile have similar lines of code. See my updated question.

Comment: Excuse me, @Rich Homolka, but I would like to know why do you say that `-i` is not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez if you have an interactive (not a script, but active at a terminal) shell, bash pretends you gave it `-i` on the command line. Try opening a bash shell window, then `echo $-`, you should see `i` (among possibly other flags)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same behavior - probably after having git (Windows) installed.

In the system setting I've found the user variable HOME=C:\Users\me and reset this to HOME=D:\home