# cygwin doesn't pick up HOME .bashrc

Tags: cygwin

I just installed cygwin and everything is pretty good but, 
cygwin doesn't pick up .bashrc file.

```
vi ~/.bashrc
alias ls='ls -la --color'
```

after reopened a new cygwin terminal, the content is still there, but alias doesn't work.
If I run `alias ls='ls -la --color'` in the terminal, alias works but it doesn't save to .bashrc file.

I am sure I am in the user home directory `cd ~`

someone could give me a hint?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, bash is being launched as a login shell. Login shells do not automatically use the content of `.bashrc`. If you want them to do so, you can create the file `~/.profile` with this content:

```
[ -f $HOME/.bashrc ] && source $HOME/.bashrc
```

(as was mentioned in answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/395218/cygwin-bashrc-not-being-source-because-cygwin-starting-in-windows-home), although they were not relevant to that case).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I created  `~/.profile` but got this error `-bash: $'\r': command not found`

Comment: That is because your editor used Windows line endings (CR+LF, or \r\n) instead of Unix line ending (LF, or \n, only).  You can read more about it [here](http://www.techanswerguy.com/2008/02/upgrading-cygwin-dos2unix.html), for example. You can probably solve the problem by running the `dos2unix .profile` command.

Comment: dos2unix permission denied. I will try to get this sorted.thanks a lot