# CygWin terminal in remote console (SSH) not starting at correct $HOME path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cygwin, remote

I have installed [CygWin](http://cygwin.com/) v1.7.28.

**The problem quickly explained**: Basically, when starting a CygWin shell via remote login, the **$HOME** is not where it should, with all derivated (bad) consequences of it. Local consoles performs OK.

And now for the **details**:

If on the GUI (Windows XP) I do:

```
c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
```

or (same way, practically):

```
c:\CygWin\Cygwin.bat
```

I start at the correct **$HOME** with all my config files:

```
LuisRivas@portatilacer ~
$ pwd
/home/LuisRivas

LuisRivas@portatilacer ~
$ ls .* -la
-rw-------  1 LuisRivas Ninguno  108 mar  3 14:34 .bash_history
-rwxr-xr-x  1 LuisRivas Ninguno 1494 mar  3 03:00 .bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 LuisRivas Ninguno 6127 mar  3 14:28 .bashrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 LuisRivas Ninguno 1919 mar  3 03:00 .inputrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 LuisRivas Ninguno 1236 mar  3 03:00 .profile

$ echo $HOME
/home/LuisRivas
```

But if I log via SSH ([Bitvise SSH Server](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) v6 installed on Windows XP SP3) and I repeat the process (same user):

```
c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
```

Now the *Bash Shell* does not start where it should:

```
LuisRivas@portatilacer ~
$ echo $HOME
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/LuisRivas

LuisRivas@portatilacer ~
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/LuisRivas

LuisRivas@portatilacer ~
$ ls .* -la
-rw-------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno 197 mar  3 14:36 .bash_history

.:
total 1211
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administradores SYSTEM       0 mar  3 14:30 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 Administradores SYSTEM       0 mar  1 04:06 ..
-rw-------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno    197 mar  3 14:36 .bash_history
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 mar  3 14:12 Configuración local
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 dic 25 15:41 Cookies
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 mar  3 14:17 Datos de programa
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 dic 25 13:56 Entorno de red
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 dic 25 13:56 Escritorio
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 mar  3 14:12 Favoritos
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 mar  3 14:02 IETldCache
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 dic 25 13:56 Impresoras
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 dic 25 13:56 Menú Inicio
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 mar  3 14:12 Mis documentos
-rwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno 786432 mar  3 14:17 NTUSER.DAT
-rwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno   1024 mar  3 14:34 NTUSER.DAT.LOG
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Administradores SYSTEM     192 mar  3 14:03 ntuser.ini
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 dic 25 15:33 Plantillas
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 mar  3 14:12 Reciente
drwx------+ 1 LuisRivas       Ninguno      0 mar  3 14:12 SendTo
```

That is: *CygWin* started the shell at my Windows home directory, so I don't have my personalizations (**.bashrc**, **.bash_profile** ... etc), like aliases.

Maybe this strange behavior is just caused by some kind of missing environment variable (that exists on GUI, but not on remote console), but I have not been able to locate it.
How could I do to make my remote console to start the *Bash Shell* included in *CygWin* where it should?

- EDIT: here some extra data upon request:

At local Bash Shell:

```
LuisRivas@portatilacer ~
$ id
uid=1004(LuisRivas) gid=513(Ninguno) grupos=513(Ninguno),0(root),544(Administradores),545(Usuarios)
```

At remote Bash Shell (nothing differs):

```
LuisRivas@portatilacer ~
$ id
uid=1004(LuisRivas) gid=513(Ninguno) grupos=513(Ninguno),0(root),544(Administradores),545(Usuarios)
```

And this is the content of /etc/passwd (only shown the user "LuisRivas" line):

```
LuisRivas@portatilacer ~
$ cat /etc/passwd
[Lines not needed (I think)]
LuisRivas:unused:1004:513:U-PORTATILACER\LuisRivas,S-1-5-21-789336058-1957994488-1417001333-1004:/home/LuisRivas:/bin/bash
[Lines not needed (I think)]
```

- EDIT 2: In a first writing I was wrong: the file **.bashrc** at the starting path (wherever this path is) is read OK by *CygWin* when starting its shell. That info is deleted now.
- EDIT 3: My tests have only been made on SSH remote logins, not Telnet. So came the problem: precisely from some behavior of Bitvise SSH Server (read response below).

Comment: There several possible issues at hand. What does your `/etc/passwd` say? Also try to issue `id` in each case and let us know the result. Last, if you send remote commands via SSH, then they might be executed as `cyg_server` and not as the SSH user.

Comment: I have edited the question to add those details. I pasted from /etc/passwd only the line concerning to the logged user. Thanks, @user1147688.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Please also try `editrights.exe -l -u LuisRivas` and `mkpasswd --local |grep LuisRivas`.

Comment: You should look at the solution to the very similar issue [here](http://superuser.com/q/395218/116221).

Comment: That's correct, friend. That was the solution.. I have posted it as an answer to be easy to read.

Comment: @user1147688, when I posted my answer as a proposed solution I was still a newbie. The netiquette logical for this case is for you to have priority in posting it as an answer, and so get the reputation points. You can copy&paste my answer if you want, and I will remove the mine. Excuse me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in just a few words: [Bitvise SSH Server](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) (Windows) adds an (supposedly illogical; seems not to be needed) environment variable **%HOME%** that equals to **%HOMEPATH%**.

The solution: the possibility of managing the environment variables that Bitvise SSH Server adds to every SSH client (*Putty*, classic GNU command-line *SSH*... etc). As long as I have researched about, the program doesn't have this functionality. I will keep searching.

Workarounds:

1. Call the *Bash Shell* via a *.cmd* file that first deletes the **%HOME%** environment variable. Something like:

   @ set HOME=
   @ c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
2. Starting the *Bash Shell* by changing the **$HOME** value, and restarting it:

   c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe --login -i -c "export HOME=/home/%USERNAME%;cd /home/%USERNAME%; exec /bin/bash"
3. Just copying all configuration files from *c:\CygWin\home\%USERNAME%* to *c:\User\%USERNAME%*. Seems to work OK (does anybody knows about some issue with this method?).

Thanks to @user1147688 (above) for ideas and link to solution from a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/395218/cygwin-bashrc-not-being-source-because-cygwin-starting-in-windows-home).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was not due to a Windows environmental variable %HOME% that I was able to delete. No %HOME% variable was listed in the Environmental Variables dialog box.

Instead, I was able to solve the problem in Bitvise by unchecking "Permit environmental variables" in the advanced settings. I also deleted "%HOME%" in the field *Initial terminal shell directory*, but that wasn't enough by itself.